Subdifferential of supremum norm on a space of continuous functions
For any Banach space $X$ with dual $X^*$, let the subdifferential of its norm be defined by
$$ \partial \| x \| := \{ x^* \in X^* : \|x^*\| = 1, \langle x, x^* \rangle = \| x \| \}. $$
I would like to know how to characterize these sets for $X = C(K)$, $K \subseteq \mathbb R^d$ compact, equipped with the supremum norm. I.e., the set $\partial \| f \|_\infty$ for any given $f \in C(K)$. It is easily verified that $$S := \{ \operatorname{sgn} f(x) \delta_{x} : x \in K \text{ such that } \| f \|_\infty = |f(x)| \} $$ is contained in $\partial \| f \|_\infty$. Together with this similar question, I am led to the conjecture that $\partial \| f\|_\infty$ is in fact the weak${}^*$-closed convex hull of $S$.
Is this true? If so, is there a good reference for the proof this result? I have tried to prove it myself but I struggle to get the details right.

I am not sure if it is true. Notice that $C= \partial |f|_\infty$ is convex and weak-star compact so that by the Krein - Smulian theorem, it is the (weak-star) closed convex hull of its extreme points. Now, each element in $S$ is an extreme point of $C$ but I am not sure if every extreme point of $C$ is in fact an element of $S$...

@EvangelopoulosFoivos: Good point! I think this is the case, actually. I will write it out as an answer. (Small comment: I think you meant Krein–Milman instead of Smulian)

I think it is true. As commented by Evangelopoulos Foivos, by the Banach–Alaoglu and Krein–Milman theorems it suffices to show that $S$ coincides with the set $\operatorname{ext}(\partial \| f \|_\infty)$ of extreme points of $\partial \| f \|_\infty$, with the difficult inclusion being $\operatorname{ext}(\partial \| f \|_\infty) \subseteq S$.
A result known as the Arens–Kelley theorem states that the extreme points of the closed unit ball $\overline B_{C(K)^*}$ in $C(K)^*$ are precisely given by $\{ \pm \delta_x : x \in K \}$. Thus, if we can show that extreme points of $\partial \| f \|_\infty$ are also extreme points of $\overline B_{C(K)^*}$, then for any $x^* \in \operatorname{ext}(\partial \| f \|_\infty)$ we have $x^* = r \delta_x$ for some $r \in \{-1,1\}$ and $x \in K$, and from $\| f \| = \langle f, x^* \rangle = r f(x)$ it follows that $r = \operatorname{sgn} f(x)$ and $\| f \| = |f(x)|$, hence $x^* \in S$.
This claim can be proven as follows. Firstly, for convenience we note that we could also take $\| x^* \| \le 1$ instead of $\| x^* \| = 1$ in the definition of the subdifferential of the norm. Now let $x^*$ be an extreme point of $\partial \| f \|_\infty$. Moreover, suppose that $x_0^*, x_1^* \in \overline B_{C(K)^*}$ and $\lambda \in (0,1)$ are such that
$$
x^* = (1 - \lambda) x_0^* + \lambda x_1^*. \qquad (*)
$$
If we can show that $x_0^*, x_1^* \in \partial \| f \|_\infty$, then the assumption that $x^*$ is an extreme point of $\partial \| f \|_\infty$ yields $x_0^* = x_1^* = x^*$ and thus $x^*$ is also an extreme point of $\overline B_{C(K)^*}$ as claimed. Since $\| x_0^* \|, \| x_1^* \| \le 1$, it suffices to prove $\langle f, x_0^* \rangle =\langle f, x_1^* \rangle = \| f \|$. First note that $\langle f, x_0^* \rangle \le \| f \| \| x_0^* \| \le \| f \|$. On the other hand, $(*)$ and $x^* \in \partial \| f\|_\infty$ imply
$$
\| f\| = (1 - \lambda) \langle f, x_0^* \rangle + \lambda \langle f, x_1^* \rangle \le (1 - \lambda) \langle f, x_0^* \rangle + \lambda \| f \|,
$$
which can be rearranged to read $\| f \| \le \langle f, x_0^* \rangle$, so together we have $\| f \| = \langle f, x_0^* \rangle$. Arguing analogously, we also obtain $\| f \| = \langle f, x_1^* \rangle$, and the proof is finished.
